# Avoid printing of default hibernate exception log report in logfile

Tags: hibernate, logging, printing, default

I wrote a java program, used *hibernate* in it. While running that java program in linux, i am getting hibernate log printed into a log file which is occupying huge memory due to inbuilt exception reports such as constraint voilation exception, when starting session factory etc . But i dont want hibernate inbuilt log statements to print inorder to avoid memory occupancy. What should i do?

**My Exception log report which i dont want to print in logfile:**

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43) at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235) at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27) at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338) at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.tcs.rapdrp.main.MyThread.run(InsertionData.java:238)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (tablename.columnname) violated
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10070)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242) ... 8 more
```

Comment: Which logger tool are you using?

Comment: I am new to hibernate, i donot know how to use logger tool and which logger to use. Please help me in how can i use logger tool in java

Comment: Thanku pramod, i have used log4j and now i am able to get rid of it.

Comment: Good..!! your problem resolved..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is exactly what log files are meant for - to capture exceptions and related stack-trace so that you can pinpoint what went wrong.
The log are saved in plain text file and I don't think in normal scenarios cause memory issues.

Use a logger tool such as `log4j` and change the log level you will be able to disable the logs.
Check if you have set log level as `DEBUG` for your application. You can change it to `ERROR` or `WARNING` as appropriate.